# Passing argument by void** to function

Tags: c, c89

I'm trying to pass arguments by a function using a `void *` to give any type of arguments. But for some reasons I don't understand, no data can be read inside of the function.

This is a reproduced behaviour of a company function. 
[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa0093f02eafd268)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    double d1, d2;
} S;

double doStuff(void ** args)
{
    double * a = (double*)args;

    printf("a[0] = %lf\n", a[0]);
    printf("a[1] = %lf\n", a[1]);

    double r = a[0] + a[1];
    return r;
}

int main(void) {

    S s;
    s.d1 = 10.0;
    s.d2 = 10.0;

    S* ptr = &s;

    void* args[2];
    args[0] = &ptr->d1;
    args[1] = &ptr->d2;

    double d = doStuff(args);

    printf("d = %lf\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

And it's output

```
a[0] = 0.000000
a[1] = 0.000000
d = 0.000000
```

Comment: `void **` is *not* the same as `void *`.

Comment: funny: I get `a[0] = 0.000000
a[1] = 10.000000
d = 10.000000`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre using gcc or clang ?

Comment: `gcc` in my case.

Comment: `double * a = (double*)args;` --> `double a[] = { *(double*)args[0], *(double*)args[1] };` (and try `%lf` --> `%f` )

Comment: That looks like a very bad idea. Don't use `void *` without **a good** reason. As you instantly cast to `double *`, use a parameter of this type. As a sidenote: don'tr use ancient C89/90! Use modern, standard C, i.e. C11, at least C99.

Comment: The function is basically a wrapper around [mono_runtime_invoke](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/#invoking-a-method), so that's why it's using `void**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to:

```
double doStuff(void ** args)
{
    double ** a = (double**)args;

    printf("a[0] = %lf\n", *a[0]);
    printf("a[1] = %lf\n", *a[1]);

    double r = *a[0] + *a[1];
    return r;
}
```

**EDIT**

The OP asked for a change in `main` instead of `doStuff` (which s/he does not own).

Now, as noted by @Eugene Sh, the function `doStuff` is crippled because it asks for a double pointer argument, but uses as a pointer to double.

The change in main is just pass around a pointer to double, but cast to `void**` just to make the compiler happy:

```
int main(void) {

    S s;
    s.d1 = 10.0;
    s.d2 = 10.0;

    S* ptr = &s;

    double args[2];     // our pointer to double
    args[0] = ptr->d1;
    args[1] = ptr->d2;

    double d = doStuff((void**)args); // cast to void**

    printf("d = %lf\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that from the outside? I'm not really able to modify that function

Comment: You kind of *must* to. Otherwise you are casting `void **` to `double*`, which are incompatible.

Comment: If you cannot change `doStuff()` then you must past a `double*` cast to a `void**`, so that the code in there is well defined. That is: `double args[2]; doStuff((void**)args);`.

Comment: [Seems like it does not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44b135d3f01d59fe). Maybe it's because it's ANSI-C

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne you forgot to change the lines `args[0] = &ptr->d1; args[1] = &ptr->d2;` to `args[0] = ptr->d1; args[1] = ptr->d2;` (not that the reference operator is gone).

Comment: Oops, my bad. It works on my coliru example but it fails on my local code, I'll inverstigate that later on. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @rodrigo I don't think casting incompatible pointer types is well defined. They can even have different size on some exotic systems. The function is just broken according to standard C.

Comment: It is as in the C pointers are addresses. No garbage collections, no anything.